# Let controller handle segue from UIScrollView table didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

my current "layer" path looks like this:

```
UITabBarController
`-- UINavigationController
    `-- UIViewController
        `-- UIScrollView
            `-- UIView
                `-- UITableView
                    `-- UITableViewController
```

I have the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` listener on the `UITableViewController`, but since this is programatically added and doesn't actually exist in the storyboard there are no `push` `segue`'s to handle the interaction. I was wondering how I could pass this "up the chain" to my `UIViewController`?

Thanks - the code in the `UIViewController` which creates the `UIScrollView` looks like this:

```
CGRect frame  = _scrollView.bounds;
float  width  = _scrollView.bounds.size.width;
float  height = _scrollView.bounds.size.height;

[_scrollView setDelegate:self];
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width * 3, height)];
[_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

UIView      * viewItem  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; frame = CGRectOffset(frame, width, 0);
UITableView * tableItem = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
self setConItem:[[UITableViewControllerItem alloc] init]];

[_conItem load:@"item" withTable:tableItem];

tableItem.dataSource = _conItem;
tableItem.delegate   = _conItem;

[viewItem addSubview:tableItem];

[_scrollView addSubview:viewItem];
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't put a `UITableView` in `UIScrollView`.  In any case take a look at the UIStoryboard reference and you'll find hooks to manually instantiate view controllers and can go from there.

Comment: @David Why shouldn't you do that? Looking into grabbing the controller from the storyboard and then `segue`'ing from there, thanks.